# Trying to open popup through jquery containing html syntax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm Trying  to open popup through jquery containing html syntax.but not getting proper idea.I have open an alert as shown below ex but how to open this HTML.The example code which i have shared gets data dynamically in mvc and on clicking that hyperlink i want to open an html page which should also contain dynamically data 'Html' code is given below.Any idea would be appreciated.
HTML

```
<body>
   <table>
       <tr>
           <td>zone</td><td>Date</td>           
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>CreatedBy</td><td>CreatedDate</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>ClosedBy</td><td>ClosedDate</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Pririty</td><td>IssueType</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Branch/Location</td><td>IssueDescription</td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       <select>
    <option value="Open">Open</option>
    <option value="Closed">Closed</option>    
      </select>     
        <textarea>Description</textarea>
    <select>
        <option value="Open">Open</option>
        <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
    </select> 
    <textbox>Attachment</textbox>      
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

</body>
```

asp.net mvc

```
<td id="statusdiv_@item.EscId" class="statusdiv">@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status).ToString(), "Escalation")</td>
```

jquery

```
$('.statusdiv').click(function () {       
            alert('hello');
 });
```

Comment: Just create the html in a hidden element and display the element in the click event and its just a matter of styling it as a dialog (e.g. [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/)). But there are plenty of plugins with this functionality including [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)